# in react js how copy only selected objects from an array to another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with 3 objects inside it. I would like to copy only two of these objects into a new array.
This is a structure:

```
Object { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AB", label: "Books" }  

Object { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AC", label: "Cars" }  

Object { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AE", label: "House" }
```

I would like to have AB and AE but not AC in a new array. How can I do it?

```
var dataArray2 = [];
        dataArray2.push(dataArray[1]); 
        dataArray2.push(dataArray[3]);
```

This code did not work.

Comment: Is the `id` the only criteria there? if so `dataArray2 = dataArray.filter( ({ id }) => ['AB', 'AE'].includes(id) );` Your example does not work because indexes are 0 based, so you should do `dataArray[0]` and `dataArray[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array.filter to filter the array based on your condition.
and it returns new array.

```js
let dataArray  = [
  { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AB", label: "Books" },
  { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AC", label: "Cars" },
  { active: true, contributionAmount: 31, id: "AE", label: "House" } 
];
let dataArray2 = dataArray.filter(ele=>ele.id !== "AC");
console.log(dataArray2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start at index 0, so first and third elements would be indexes 0 and 2.

```
var dataArray2 = [];
dataArray2.push(dataArray[0]); 
dataArray2.push(dataArray[2]);
```